# Compare items in two lists and replace foreach loop with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, foreach, concurrentdictionary

I have two Lists:

```
   List<Item1> list1;
   List<Item2> list2;
```

I have following code for compearing items in Lists:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> compareDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lis1.Count; i++)
{
   var item1Name= list1[i].Name.ToString();
   var item1Id= list1[i].ID.ToString();

   foreach (var item in list2)
   {
      if (item1Name.Contains(item.item2Name.ToLower()))
      {
          compareDictionary.TryAdd(item1Id, item.item2Id);
      }
    }
}
```

It is needed to add `Id` from the first List an `Id` from the second one into ConcurrentDictionary, if `Name` of one item contains part of another one. 
It works, but I want to simplify the algorithm and remove the `foreach` and `if`.

Comment: Can you please share properties of `Item1` and `Item1`?

Comment: Join the two lists together with AddRange,  eg. list1.AddRange(list2); Then list1.Distinct(). If you wanted to match on only some of the properties, then you would need to create a custom equality comparer,

Comment: @level_zebra the lists are of different types, you'll get a compilation error trying to AddRange list2 to list1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the inner loop using System.Linq. Also simplify code by using foreach instead of for for main loop:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> compareDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var element in list1)
{
   var item1Name= element.Name.ToString();
   var item1Id= element.ID.ToString();
   // If this element has already one correspondence, TryAdd will fail anyway
   if(compareDictionary.ContainsKey(item1Id)) continue; 

   var found = list2.FirstOrDefault(item => item1Name.Contains(item.item2Name.ToLower()));
   if(found != null)
   {
          compareDictionary.TryAdd(item1Id, item.item2Id);
   }
}
```

Depending on your elements naming, you also could need to make item1Name lower case.
Your code will in fact find this correspondence:

```
Parentwithlittlechild --> LittleChild
```

but not this:

```
ParentWithLittleChild --> LittleChild
```

because "LittleChild" would be lower cased, and String.Contains works case sensitively by default.
You could also use `IndexOf` method with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, like this:

```
var found = list2.FirstOrDefault(item => item1Name.IndexOf(item.item2Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Final consideration: `element.Name` is probably already of type string, unless your `Item1.Name` property is some funny type. If so, `element.Name.ToString()` is convertible in just `element.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of code snippets to find the matches and add the `ids` of the two objects in a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>`.

So we have:

```cs
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
```

**First**

```cs
list1.ForEach(x =>
{
    list2.Where(y => y.Item2Name.IndexOf(x.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList().ForEach(y => dict.TryAdd(x.ID, y.Item2Id));
});
```

**Second**

```cs
(from x in list1
    from y in list2
    where x.Name.IndexOf(y.Item2Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    select (x, y)).ToList().ForEach(item => dict.TryAdd(item.x.ID, item.y.Item2Id));
```

**Side Note**

- If both `Item1.Name` and `Item2.Item2Name` properties are of `string` type, then no need to use `ToString()` function like in `var item1Name= list1[i].Name.ToString();` line.
- If both `Item1.ID` and `Item2.Item2Id` properties are of `int` type, then the proper type of both `Key` and `Value` pairs of the dictionary is the `int` type. So:

```cs
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
```